# Terraform template_file get pass all received variables to a function

Tags: variables, terraform

is there in Terraforom in template_files a way to pass through all the received variables to other place?
I mean something similar than $@ in bash.

For example:

```
resource "template_file" "some_template" {
    template = "my_template.tpl")}"
    vars {
        var1 = "value1"
        var2 = "value2"
    }
}
```

and then from the rendered file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Var1: ${var1}"
echo "Var2: ${var2}"

echo "But I want it in someway similar to this:"
for v in $@; do 
  echo "$v"; 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, no.

From https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html

> Variables for interpolation within the template. Note that variables
>   must all be primitives. Direct references to lists or maps will cause
>   a validation error.

Primitives in terraform are string, number and boolean.

So it means you can not pass a hash or a list to group all the variables in one.

Answer (score 0):

Use [join](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/join.html) and pass all the variables as one and parse/split them within a script (with `tr`/`IFS` tricks)

```
join("; ", [var.myvar1, var.myvar2, var.myvar3])
```

and then

```
IN="${allvars}"
IFS=';' read -ra ADDR <<< "$IN"
for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```